# Click fires under the absolute component

Tags: javascript, react-native

Have some problem with my component. I make dropdown menu, and when I clicked on TextInput,I show absolute component at the bottom of prev TextInput.But if under my target component something which I can interact too, my dropdown doesn't reacts on my click.Zindex didn't helped.
react native 0.61.3
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Gjm.png)

Comment: Hi Vlad, are you able to provide some example code that is causing the issue along with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. Use this

```
    //import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```